# In amazon lightsail, where do i see the total bandwidth used for my cloudfront distribution?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-lightsail

I have a lightsail account with a CF distribution and I want to see the total bytes downloaded this month to avoid overage fees. The metric graphs under metrics only show average bytes downloaded per hour and only goes back 2 weeks. But where's the total bytes downloaded this month?